# Applying dmap on a dataset() in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dataset

What does this piece of code do in Python with a dataset in Pytorch?

```
datasets = split_dataset(dataset(),splits=split)    
datasets['_unlab'] = dmap(lambda mb: mb[0],dataset())
```

The second line seems particularly cryptic.

And here is a link to split_dataset and dmap

[Code for Split dataset](https://github.com/mfinzi/olive-oil-ml/blob/master/oil/datasetup/datasets.py)

[Code for dmap](https://github.com/mfinzi/olive-oil-ml/blob/master/oil/utils/utils.py)

Comment: What is `split_dataset`? And, how was `dmap` imported?

Comment: I changed the question to answer to this comment.